# How to properly clear a remote LAN connection?

Tags: windows, windows-authentication, unc

I am on a Windows centric LAN without a domain.

I have access to several machines on my network, each with different username and passwords.
I originally connected to them with a UNC path in explorer and entered in the authentication information.

Now when I type in explorer I can access the machine without entering a username and password.

What I'm trying to do is get that prompt again without logging off.  I know I can clear connections using:

> net use * /delete

My connections are no longer listed now, but I can still go in explorer and access the shares without a username and password.

If I log off and back on the problem is fixed, I will be prompted again for the auth info.
But logging off is inconvenient for me.

Is there a better way to clear the auth info so I will be prompted when trying to access an administrative UNC share?

I do notice that if I wait long enough I will eventually get the prompt again.  Is there a way to eliminate this timeout though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can view the saved credentials with start -> Run -> **rundll32.exe keymgr.dll, KRShowKeyMgr**

However I'm guessing you want the live cached connections to be flushed out and that box probably won't help. You may be able to clear these sessions using **net session \\computername /DELETE**. In theory this will flush out your connection to a given remote machine.

Comment: Is there a shortcut somewhere in control panel or somewhere else to that same place as the rundll32.exe command?

Comment: On XP it should be under Control Panel -> User Accounts -> Stored Usernames and Passwords. On Vista and 7, I've only been able to find an updated 'pretty' version under Control Panel -> User Accounts -> Credential Manager

Comment: If none of this works, MS's position seems to be 'always log the user off once you're done. See here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/281249/

Answer (score 1):

Without trying this from a keyboard, you could explicity setup your connection:

`net use \\<remotepc>\ipc$ <password> /user:<remotepc>\<username>`

...then you can remove this when finished:

`net use \\<remotepc>\ipc$ /d`